# Windows event 4771 , different use case between computer and user

Tags: windows, security

I am using powershell to get audit fail events 4625 and 4771 from the Domain Controllers. Most of these are 0x18 Status. Now i understand the events with usernames (don't end in a $) as having bad passwords from a machine. Most of the google examples show 4771's from users.

> What i want to understand, is what it means when it is coming from a machine?

i.e. surely it is an account on the machine which has an issue, how does a machine have a bad password? And if it can, how does one find out what the issue is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active Directory is an identity management system, and so anything that authenticates with Active Directory needs an "identity" of some sort. Since computers themselves can be joined to a domain and must authenticate against it (with a username and password via Kerberos the same as a regular user logon), they have a username. The AD machine account username is the computer's DNS hostname followed by a dollar sign, for example: Desktop-AB123$

Since every computer in the domain must authenticate against the domain with a username and password, it is possible for that authentication to fail. And it can fail for all of the same reasons that a regular user logon can fail: unrecognized or misspelled username, incorrect password, wrong domain or UPN suffix, or any number of authentication errors.

Event ID 4771 indicates a Kerberos preauthentication error and status 0x18 (usually) indicates a bad password. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-4771).

Machine accounts renegotiate their password automatically with the Domain Controller when they connect to the domain. If a domain-joined workstation is unable to communicate with a domain controller long enough for the password to expire, it will not be able to log in and you will get a failed logon for that computer's machine name. The computer will need to be rejoined to the domain (or have its password reset using [Reset-ComputerMachinePassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/reset-computermachinepassword?view=powershell-5.1) and a domain admin credential). The same is also true if a domain controller is unable to communicate with the PDC Emulator. This will be the most common type of error that will lead to failed machine account logins. The second most common will probably be due to computers being renamed while unable to contact a DC, changing the computer's logon username without updating AD.

Beyond password expiration or computer renames, you have to start looking deeper for root causes. These are likely going to be Kerberos negotiation errors caused by services attempting to authenticate in order to perform certain actions. Note that the authentication error does *not* necessarily occur at service start and may occur when the service is accessed or triggered by another application. I recommend reviewing my [question & answer in ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1007587/why-is-vss-creating-failed-logon-events-event-id-4625-when-azure-ad-connect-is) regarding one such example where a server's DNS name didn't match its NETBIOS name, which caused Kerberos authentication to fail and fall back to NTLM.

As that ServerFault question illustrates, tracking down the root cause of a failed machine logon, once you've ruled out username and password errors, can be *extremely* difficult. Your first step should probably be to [enable Netlogon debug logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/windows-security/enable-debug-logging-netlogon-service) and then searching the netlogon log file for your failure events. You can also search the SYSTEM event log for any events related to services failing to start. After those two starting points you're basically on your own and will need to develop some advanced troubleshooting and investigation skills to track down the root cause.

One final note, your question is not exactly related to programming or software development, so [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) might be a better place for questions such as this in the future. ServerFault is geared towards professional sys admins working in production environments while SuperUser is more geared towards hobbyists, enthusiasts, home servers, and DIYers.

Comment: Thanks and apologies for the delay